# Can I or can I not use addin manager in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017, add-in, rhapsody

So I have an old Rhapsody addin (RhaspodyAddin.AddIn) that I can't convert to VSIX package file because its 3rd party.

Looking at the online docs: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dax6cz.aspx) it suggests that I need to add the addin in the addin manager. But the addin Manager is gone in msvs2017 (I am converting a project from MSVS2012 which does have addin manager).

It says that addins are deprecated since 2013.

So does anyone know what I need to do to use this older .addin style addin or if it is even possible anymore in MSVS2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddIns are no longer supported in Visual Studio, you must ask the vender for a Vspackage based extension (using the .vsix file format)

Comment: dang :( ... Can you convert a .addin file into a vspackage easily (i.e. just translate the content) or is that non-trivial?